# How to implement google translate in SPFx extension in SharePoint Online?

Tags: spfx-extensions, google-translate

We were using google translate API in our SharePoint Online classic view site. Now we are moving to modern site. I need to implement same in SPFx extension.

Below is code to that is working in classic view:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Now I am using same in my SPFx extension as below:

```
public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, `Initialized ${strings.Title}`);    
    SPComponentLoader.loadScript('https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit');

    this.context.placeholderProvider.changedEvent.add(this, this._renderPlaceHolders);
    this.googleTranslateElementInit();
     return Promise.resolve<void>();
  }


  private googleTranslateElementInit() {
    //Getting error here can not find name "google"
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
  }
  private _onDispose(): void {
    console.log('[HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer._onDispose] Disposed custom top and bottom placeholders.');
  }
  private _renderPlaceHolders(): void {
    console.log("HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer._renderPlaceHolders()");
    console.log(
        "Available placeholders: ",
        this.context.placeholderProvider.placeholderNames
            .map(name => PlaceholderName[name])
            .join(", ")
    );    

    // Handling the bottom placeholder
    if (!this._bottomPlaceholder) {
        this._bottomPlaceholder = this.context.placeholderProvider.tryCreateContent(
            PlaceholderName.Bottom,
            { onDispose: this._onDispose }
        );

        // The extension should not assume that the expected placeholder is available.
        if (!this._bottomPlaceholder) {
            console.error("The expected placeholder (Bottom) was not found.");
            return;
        }

        if (this.properties) {
            let bottomString: string = this.properties.bottom;
            if (!bottomString) {
                bottomString = "Language Translate";
            }

            if (this._bottomPlaceholder.domElement) {                
                this._bottomPlaceholder.domElement.innerHTML = `                
                ${bottomString}<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
                `;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am facing issue in below code in `googleTranslateElementInit()` method - can not find name 'google'

```
new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
```

I am not sure how to get this resolved? I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173662/typescript-error-cannot-find-name-google-in-ionic2-when-using-googlemaps-javas) link. But didn't fix my issue.

How to fix this issue? Is there any other API that we can use for translation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translator API expects global function available (you pass the name of this function via `cb=` query parameter).

To make it work, you should create this globally available function, i.e. attach it to window object:

```
public onInit(): Promise<void> {

    window['googleTranslateElementInit'] = () => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-expression
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
    };

    return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit', {
      globalExportsName: 'google'
    });
  }
```

I haven't found TypeScript definitions for translate api, so I had to add `declare var google;` on top of the file to make TS compilation happy.

Also, you should provide `globalExportsName` because SPFx somehow tries to validate it as a module and throws an error.

Comment: im receiving error when trying this code , cannot read property 'translate'